# Azure automating CNAME checks in DNS zones?

Tags: azure, dns, azure-dns, azure-private-dns-zone

Is it possible to access these CNAME and other entries through some sort of scripting? I tried using a logic app but could only access the resource group, name, subscription id, etc. but not the more detailed information such as the record sets that are displayed when 'overview' is selected in a given DNS zone.

Perhaps AzCLI or powershell? Any push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the DNS records with the [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/private-dns-getstarted-cli) or [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/private-dns-getstarted-powershell).

For example, to list the DNS records in your private DNS zone, run the PowerShell command [Get-AzPrivateDnsRecordSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.privatedns/get-azprivatednsrecordset?view=azps-5.3.0#example-3--get-all-record-sets-in-a-private-zone):

```
$RecordSets = Get-AzPrivateDnsRecordSet -ResourceGroupName "MyResourceGroup" -ZoneName "myzone.com"

Id                : /subscriptions/xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/myresourcegroup/providers/Micros
                    oft.Network/privateDnsZones/myzone.com/AAAA/www1
Name              : www1
ZoneName          : myzone.com
ResourceGroupName : MyResourceGroup
Ttl               : 3600
Etag              : xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
RecordType        : A
Records           : {1.2.3.4}
Metadata          :
IsAutoRegistered  :

Id                : /subscriptions/xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/myresourcegroup/providers/Micros
                    oft.Network/privateDnsZones/myzone.com/AAAA/www1
Name              : www1
ZoneName          : myzone.com
ResourceGroupName : MyResourceGroup
Ttl               : 3600
Etag              : xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
RecordType        : AAAA
Records           : {2001:DB80:4009:1803::1005}
Metadata          :
IsAutoRegistered  :
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. It's working as expected. We have public DNS, and you can get those records as well by issuing Get-AzDnsRecordSet instead.